# How to set Countdown For Each Candidate using Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery

I am working on online Q/A system,i have to show countdown for each candidate like 3 min,on expiring user will be redirect to Result.aspx page.
I am facing following 
1.how to set counter for each candidate.
2.on page refresh counter set to default value.
i have following code

```
<div id="timer">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function countdown(minutes) {
            var seconds = 60;
            var mins = minutes;

            if (getCookie("minutes") && getCookie("seconds")) {
                var seconds = getCookie("seconds");
                var mins = getCookie("minutes");
            }

            function tick() {

                var counter = document.getElementById("timer");
                setCookie("minutes", mins, 10)
                setCookie("seconds", seconds, 10)
                var current_minutes = mins - 1
                seconds--;
                counter.innerHTML =
                current_minutes.toString() + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);
                //save the time in cookie
                //minutesSpan.innerHTML = current_minutes.toString();
                //secondsSpan.innerHTML = (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);
                if (seconds > 0) {
                    setTimeout(tick, 1000);
                }
                else {
                    if (mins > 1) {
                        // countdown(mins-1);   never reach “00″ issue solved:Contributed by Victor Streithorst    
                        setTimeout(function () { countdown(mins - 1); }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            }
            tick();
        }
        function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
            var d = new Date();
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
            document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
        }
        function getCookie(cname) {
            var name = cname + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                    return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
        countdown(3);
    </script>
```

because multiple user will doing these test so i have handle each one differently,i have following code to assign to assign test for each candidate

```
private void NewCandidate()

        {

            var ClistCount = (from cl in ef.Candidate_Table where cl.Name == btnname.Text && cl.Status_Id==2 select cl).FirstOrDefault();
            if (ClistCount != null)
            {               
                string cnic = ClistCount.Cnic;            
                Session["token"] = cnic;
                Response.Redirect("MainTestForm.aspx?id=" + cnic);
            }
            else
            {
                MsgLitteral.ShowNotification("No Candidate Is Here", true);
                btnbrowse.Visible = false;
                btnname.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things which you need to do in order to make things working
1) Create perfectly working count down timer method
2) Solve the reload dependency

- for reload thing just before reload/refresh, trigger a function that would store the current time elapsed from the predefined count down.

```js
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
  //below function stores current elapsed time in cookie/local storage
   callFunction();
    return true;
});
```

- for e.g if 3min countdown is set and the user refreshes or moves to
  next  question at 2min 40 secs then store 2min 40 sec in cookies or
  html5 local storage
- On every document ready event check the cookie value
  if value present then
   take this value and set countdown 
  else
    with predefined value (for the first time case)

[A simple countdown timer for reference](http://www.sitepoint.com/build-javascript-countdown-timer-no-dependencies/)